# Wordpress custom query search slow

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a wordpress website contain large number of posts,i have written a custom query and pass it to the `WP_Query()`,here is the structure of array

```
Array
(
    [post_type] => Array
        (
            [0] => post
            [1] => innovations
        )

    [tag] => 
    [posts_per_page] => 10
    [paged] => 1
    [s] => 
    [tax_query] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [relation] => OR
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [taxonomy] => sector
                            [field] => id
                            [terms] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 15394
                                    [1] => 15399
                                    [2] => 15436
                                )

                            [include_children] => 1
                            [operator] => IN
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [relation] => OR
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [taxonomy] => business-model
                            [field] => id
                            [terms] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 15448
                                )

                            [include_children] => 1
                            [operator] => IN
                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [relation] => OR
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [taxonomy] => technology
                            [field] => id
                            [terms] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 15470
                                    [1] => 15471
                                )

                            [include_children] => 1
                            [operator] => IN
                        )

                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [relation] => OR
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [taxonomy] => topic
                            [field] => id
                            [terms] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => 15456
                                )

                            [include_children] => 1
                            [operator] => IN
                        )

                )

        )

    [orderby] => Array
        (
            [post_date] => DESC
        )

)
```

It is working as expected ,but it take time to execute this query,this is very slow.is there any other way to improve its performance

Answer (score 0):

It is har do tell without being able to see your data structures, be able to benchmark various parameters etc.

What you can definitely do is caching that. If you do ot need this query to be run in realtime then uYou can use WordPress transients system to store the results of the query for the desired time - like seconds, minutes or even hours (That depends on use case).
https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API

Afterwards this query will be run only once per specific set of time not affecting every page load of every user.

The downside is that there will be still a user which will hit the page and the load will be slow for him - what you can do in this situation is that you can set up WordPress Cron task to regenerate results of that query every `n seconds`.

Alternatively you can use various WordPress cache plugins but this might be too much for your scenario.
(for example -> https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-super-cache/)

Comment: caching is not possible,it is from search ,user can change search criteria

Comment: You can always cache it per search term. But I agree it will be a problem.